# Is there a way to write sql query in RDBMS for CDR (Call Data Records) of every call customer makes.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, aggregate-functions

Its an interesting question I came across with.
I have an table

```
create table phonebook(
    customer_id (varchar 30)
    call_start_day (date)
    call_end_day (date)
    call_start_time (varchar 30)
    call_end_time (varchar 30)
    called_number (integer)
    customer_call_location_city (varchar 30)
    customer_call_location_state (varchar 30)
    customer_call_location_zip (integer)
    called_number_city (varchar 30)
    called_number_state (varchar 30)
    )
```

I need to to find top n customer based on average monthly call_duration in last 12 months. (consider only complete months only e.g., if current date is 2021-03-07, last 12 months: 2020-03-01 – 2021-02-28. Monthly call duration = sum (call duration) where call duration = time difference of call_end_day+ call_end_time and call_start_day+call_start_time)

Solution- I thought to find out the time and then their average. Any Suggestions?

Comment: I removed inconsistent tags , please only tag database you are using. also provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Date manipulation/conversion functions are inconsistent across RDBMS's.  So pick one, then we can answer the question.

Comment: Thanks @eshirvana 
Sample is something like 
- call_start_day (date), e.g., 2021-03-02
- call_end_day (date), e.g., 2021-03-02
- call_start_time (varchar 30), e.g., 14:21:15
- call_end_time (varchar 30), e.g., 14:30:11

I am using SSMS(sql server) for this but open for Oracle analytical function even :P and sample data should have all column with 1 extra column which will be sorted on the rank of average call duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, start by working out expressions that give

- the first date you want to consider.
- the day after the last date you want to consider.

[EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)() is good for this.

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)) day_after_last,
       DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -13)) first
```

Next, figure out how to get the call duration. You haven't told us how you represent your `call_start_time` and `call_end_time`, so we can't help you with that detail. So I'll represent the duration calculation as a stored function.  It's up to you to figure out how to get the duration. Probably duration in seconds is the best way to go for call detail records.

**Pro tip** Never, never use varchars or chars to represent DATE, TIME, or DATETIME data. They always lead to confusion and grief.

Here's the way to go.

```sql
SELECT TOP (5) customer_id, 
       AVG(dbo.duration(call_start_day, call_start_time, 
                        call_end_day, call_end_time)) average
  FROM phonebook
 WHERE call_start_day >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -13))
   AND call_start_day <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))
 GROUP BY customer_id
 ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

The `WHERE` clause pulls in only the records with dates you care about.

The `ORDER BY 2 DESC` clause means order by the result set's second column, highest to lowest. The `TOP (5)` clause means display the first five rows of the ordered result set.

**Edit**

If your time columns look like `08:47:13` then you can compute the durations with [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)(). It looks like this

```sql
DATEDIFF(
   second, 
   CAST(call_start_day AS DATETIME) + CAST(call_start_time AS DATETIME),
   CAST(call_end_day AS DATETIME) + CAST(call_end_time AS DATETIME))
```

So your query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP (5) customer_id, 
       AVG(
        DATEDIFF(
          second, 
            CAST(call_start_day AS DATETIME) + 
            CAST(call_start_time AS DATETIME),
            CAST(call_end_day AS DATETIME) + 
            CAST(call_end_time AS DATETIME))) average
  FROM phonebook
 WHERE call_start_day >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -13))
   AND call_start_day <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))
 GROUP BY customer_id
 ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks @O. Jones , its a great explanation. Most of my doubts is clear even learnt something new 'EOMONTH()'

Comment: Just to add 1 more scenario, I need to check the month over month call rate growth from place A to place B for year 2020.
And call should be accounted to the month it began on. 
`
Growth rate = [ (#calls in current month - #calls in previous month) / #calls in previous month]. The growth rate should start from Feb
`
I took the call_duration_start_month using datediff from above and doing union with call_duration of last month.
But it have few errors . Any advise?

@O.Jones